# Numpy's argmax() in Swift

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm working on a project which converts user's face to emoji. I use Apple's ARKit in this purpose.

I need to get the most probable option. I wrote this code:

```
func renderer(for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else {
        return
    }
    
    let shapes = faceAnchor.blendShapes

    let browDownLeft = shapes[.browDownLeft]!.doubleValue
    let browInnerUp = shapes[.browInnerUp]!.doubleValue
    let browOuterUpLeft = shapes[.browOuterUpLeft]!.doubleValue
    
    let leftBrowMax = max(browDownLeft, browInnerUp, browOuterUpLeft)
    
    switch leftBrowMax {
    case browDownLeft:
        userFace.leftBrow = .browDown
    case browInnerUp:
        userFace.leftBrow = .browInnerUp
    case browOuterUpLeft:
        userFace.leftBrow = .browOuterUp
    default:
        userFace.leftBrow = .any
    }
}
```

I need to duplicate function's body six time (for brows, eyes and mouth sides), so I want to write it in a more convenient way. Is there any options in Swift like numpy's argmax function? Also I need to specify arguments range, because arguments for mouth should not be compared with arguments for brows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
func maxBlendShape(for blendShapes: [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation], in shape: [ARFaceAnchor.BlendShapeLocation: NSNumber]) -> Double? {
    blendShapes
        .compactMap { shape[$0] }
        .map(\.doubleValue)
        .max()
}
```

Usage would then be something like this:

```
maxBlendShape(for: [.browDownLeft, .browInnerUp, .browOuterUpLeft], in: faceAnchor.blendShapes)
```

---

Note: Nothing here is specific to `ARKit`, you just filter some keys from the dictionary and find their max value. A generic solution could look like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Value == NSNumber {
    func maxDouble(for keys: [Key]) -> Double? {
        keys
            .compactMap({self[$0]})
            .map(\.doubleValue)
            .max()
    }
}

faceAnchor.blendShapes.maxDouble(for: [.browInnerUp, .browDownLeft, .browOuterUpLeft])
```